# Custom form in ArcMap 10.6

Tags: qgis, arcmap, forms

Does anyone know the easiest method to create a form in ArcMap 10.6 similar to that available in QGIS for collecting data on a particular feature? (Is it even possible in ArcMap?) My example is inputting data about a line which represents a section of a bank along an estuary. Each line segment might have 40 attributes about it. I would like to be able to allow a user to input field data into an ArcMap form. From what I've researched so far this function isn't as readily available in ArcMap compared to QGIS? Is that correct?

Comment: Have a look at ESRI's Survey123 and ESRI Collector.  Or see Geographical Open Data Kit for a FOSS solution.

Comment: Thanks GBG. I've been looking at those but they both seem to be more about collecting data digitally in the field. My situation requires that i collect data on field data sheets and the add the collected data as attributes to lines later in GIS via a form. I could enter it into the attribute table for each feature but some things I really need a dropdown box with for example "Location of erosion on a bank" and options would be Top of bank, Upper Bank and Lower Bank. Its so easy in QGIS but ESRI don't seem to have developed this ability in ArcMap unfortunately. Maybe I missed something in ARC ?